# Table <TR> height in mozilla

Tags: css, html-table, mozilla

I have here a table with two fields in which the height of a 1-pixel and the other 100 percent. This example clearly looks in Google Chrome. But it does not work in Mozilla. How to fix in Mozilla?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <style>
    *{margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    html, body{position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;}
    table{height: 100%; width: 100%; position: relative;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%">
        <tbody height="100%" >
            <tr>
                <td height="100%" valign="top">
                    <div style="overflow: auto; height: 100%">
                        sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />sdfsdf<br />a1
                        afasdasd sdfs sdv
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="1" valign="top">
                    test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how the Mozilla engine is interpreting the HTML height attribute for the `<td>` tag, but you might get better results using CSS for the styling instead. Have you tried something like:

In the HTML...

```
<td class="shortcell">
```

In your style block...

```
td.shortcell {height: 1px; vertical-align: top;}
```

Or inline...

```
<td style="height: 1px; vertical-align: top;">
```

UPDATE: The CSS height attribute will only work on a block level element, so you can use:

```
td.shortcell {height: 1px; vertical-align: top; display: block}
```

This will work, but will be frowned upon. Probably better to put a DIV inside the table cell and apply the height to that.

The HTML...

```
<td>
  <div class="shortcell">
     contents here
  </div>
</td>
```

And the CSS:

```
.shortcell {height: 1px;}
```

Comment: Yes, you need a block level element for the height to work. See the update in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me initially in both Chrome 10 and latest FF.
And this example helped me to figure out why "**99% or 100% height sized row in a table is not auto stretchable in Chrome**".
This bug was discussed in many places but no much solution were..
So, with this working example I've managed to figure out the solution:
all I had to do is to "**make a 99% or 100% height row of table to be auto resized in Chrome 10 is to make the parent table's height 100%**"